# Eclipse VM Argument and external JAR file error

Tags: eclipse, jar, arguments, virtual-machine

I just added "-Djava.library.path=" to the "VM Arguments" under Run Configuration in Eclipse and everything works fine until I tried to add an external JAR file.  I get the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path
```

Am I not setting something properly in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception indicates that the class `gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver` tries to load a native library, which would be named `rxtxSerial.dll` on Windows and `rxtxSerial.so` on Linux, and the JVM cannot find it in the directories listed in `java.library.path`. Have you tried to add a JAR containing the library to `java.library.path`? I don't think that's possible, it has to be a directory containing the extracted library file.

Comment: It seems the "proper" way to do this in Eclipse is to set the **Native Library Location** in the `RXTXcomm.jar` in the **Java Build Path** section of the project properties.  I got it from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957700/how-to-set-the-java-library-path-from-eclipse

Answer (score 2):

If your interested I forked RXTXserial a while back since thier update "schedule" sucks. I have just ported it over to the Android platform too. We decided to move the native libs into the jar and use reflection to deploy them. The API is the same as RXTX, but everything just works. You can find jars and full project sources at:
http://code.google.com/p/nrjavaserial/

Answer (score 0):

Appearently that external library has a dependancy with another class gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
. Perhaps you will need to add that library to class path.