# Loading DLL in Java - Eclipse - JNI

Tags: java, eclipse, java-native-interface

I am trying to load a dll in java using the following code
    System.loadLibrary("mydll");

The project is placed in D:\development\project\ and i have placed the dll on D:. I then gave following VM argument in eclipse configuration 
    -Djava.library.path=D:/

But when i run i get *UnsatisifiedLinkerError*. After googling a bit, I used
    System.load("D:\mydll.dll");

but again getting the same problem, could someone can help?

Comment: I tested my classpath with this code System.getProperty("java.class.path") and placed the dll on that specific path. After that, I am getting error "Can't find dependent libraries". How can i check which libraries it is asking :S. I am using some thirdparty Dll.

Answer (score 9):

Where you specify the DLL filename in the library path, omit that. Additionally, your System.loadLibrary call should just be 'mydll'. I can tell you (from experience) that if you put the DLL in the root of your project in Eclipse (i.e., D:\Eclipse Workspace\Proj), it *should* work. Any further linker errors could be from dependency problems with finding other DLLs. The exception is the same. Use something like Dependency Walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see if your DLL relies on anything else not on the system library path.

Edit: **UnsatisfiedLinkError**: Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine cannot find an appropriate native-language definition of a method declared native -- it seems like you are using a JNI function which does not exist.

Answer (score 5):

One problem you have is:
System.load("D:\mydll.dll");
should be
System.load("D:\\mydll.dll"); 
or
System.load("D:/mydll.dll");

I have had more success with System.load, but loadlibrary is better designed for multiplatform.
It figures out the extension for you.

Answer (score 4):

Check out how to properly set up the native dependencies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957700/how-to-set-the-java-library-path-from-eclipse). Additionally, make sure you use the correct JVM: in my case, the DLL was not found because it was a 32 bit DLL, but I used the x64 JVM!

Answer (score 3):

Using `System.loadLibrary("mydll")` works fine, you can also use that one. If you used `javah` and you think with your DLL everything is fine, there are two possibilies:

1. *The JVM does not find your DLL*: In this case, your java library path is not correct (which I doubt) and you should probably set it to `.` and place your DLL in the current working dir.
2. *The JVM does not find a DLL your DLL depends on*: If you have any dependent libraries in your DLL, they are **NOT** searched by the JVM, but by Windows itself. And Windows does not know the `java.library.path`, so it will look in the system `PATH` variable for those. If you have the possibility, you can set the system `PATH` variable to the location of your DLLs before starting the JVM and everything will be fine. Or you can load all your DLLs using the JVM like this

   > System.loadLibrary("dll_1");
   >   System.loadLibrary("dll_2");
   >   System.loadLibrary("dll_3");

   where `dll_3.dll` depends on `dll_2.dll`, which depends on `dll_1.dll`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Looks like, under linux that concept doesn't work somehow, does anyone know why?

Comment: It should, worked for me under Linux as well. What kind of library are you trying to load?

Answer (score 3):

**[System.loadLibrary](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/runtime_loadlibrary.htm)** loads the DLL from the JVM path (JDK bin path).

If you want to load an explicit file with a path, use **[System.load](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_load.htm)**()

See also: [Difference between System.load() and System.loadLibrary in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016391/difference-between-system-load-and-system-loadlibrary-in-java)

```
public class MyClass
{
    static 
    {
        System.load("MyJNI.dll");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put your Almafa.dll into the C:/Java/jre7/lib or /bin sorry, I can`t remember exactly. After you have done no more configuration needed, just say

`static{
System.LoadLibrary("Almafa"); 
}`

in the class, where you want to load it. It is works only in Java project, in Android like project you need to use JNI. I had posted now the result of 3 days no sleeping :)

Answer (score 1):

I got my error resolved by using the following:

```
   static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("myDLL");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Instead of using `System.load("myDLL.dll")`

Answer (score 0):

@alee-  You can just copy and the paste the dll files in system32 folder of your windows and try to call the library through the System.loadLibrary("mydll")... i guess it may work...

Answer (score 0):

Give the library path in your project as native library location,seems to be solved.