# Loading JNI lib on Mac OS X?

Tags: java, macos, java-native-interface, jogl

**Background**

So I am attempting to load a jnilib (specifically [JOGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_OpenGL)) into Java on Mac OS X at runtime. I have been following along the relevant Stack Overflow questions:

- [Maven and the JOGL Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962718/maven-and-the-jogl-library)
- [Loading DLL in Java - Eclipse - JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535700/loading-dll-in-java-eclipse-jni)
- [How to make a jar file that include all jar files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535700/loading-dll-in-java-eclipse-jni)

The end goal for me is to package platform specific JOGL files into a JAR and unzip them into a temp directory and load them at start-up. I worked my problem back to simply attempting to load JOGL using hard-coded paths:

```
    File f = new File("/var/folders/+n/+nfb8NHsHiSpEh6AHMCyvE+++TI/-Tmp-/libjogl.jnilib");
    System.load(f.toString());
    f = new File ("/var/folders/+n/+nfb8NHsHiSpEh6AHMCyvE+++TI/-Tmp-/libjogl_awt.jnilib");
    System.load(f.toString());
```

I get the following exception when attempting to use the JOGL API:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jogl in java.library.path
```

But when I specify `java.library.path` by adding the following JVM option:

```
    -Djava.library.path="/var/folders/+n/+nfb8NHsHiSpEh6AHMCyvE+++TI/-Tmp-/"
```

Everything works fine.

---

**Question**

Is it possible use `System.load` (or some other variant) on Mac OS X as a replacement for -Djava.library.path that is invoked at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jogl always tries to auto-load all dependent libraries.
To avoid this, there should be a NativeLibLoader class where you can call disableLoading() before you load the libraries yourself via the System.load()

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for this, calling NativeLibLoader.disableLoading() before manually loading the libraries worked brilliantly.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to provide the `java.library.path` at startup. You can programmatically set it with

```
System.setProperty("java.library.path", "/var/folder/bla/foo/bar/");
```

I don't know if `System.load()` will work somehow without this library path.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However in my experience setting the 'java.library.path' at run time did not have any effect. I think this may be for similar reasons as to why you can not change the classpath at run time - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271506/why-system-setproperty-cannot-change-the-classpath-at-run-time

Comment: Then you might have had another problem with a dependent library. Setting the lib path at runtime works perfectly fine, I used to load my libraries just like that.

Comment: That's not quite true, there is a way to force re-initializing classloader with the new lib.path.

Comment: Do something like this: 

System.setProperty( "java.library.path", newPath);

  Field fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sys_paths");
  fieldSysPath.setAccessible(true);
  fieldSysPath.set(null, null);

Answer (score -3):

`System.load(...)` takes libraryName as argument. It doesn't take path to library as argument.
JVM searches for a library with specified name in the list of paths specified in `-Djava.library.path;`

Here there is nothing specific to Mac OS X. It searches for libraries in the same way on all operating systems.

Comment: that is wrong actually, System.load() will take the complete file name and System.loadLibrary will take the lib name

Comment: I think loading jnilib is mac specific (it is in my case). I have it working on Linux (.so), in mac after compilation jnilib does not load. I use mvn jetty:deploy-war -Djava.library.path=/path/to/jnilib. I have even used System.setProperty("mylib.systemclassloader", "false"); so that it would run in a servlet environment (it disables automatic loading of that library). What might be the cause?