# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniopencv_core in java.library.path

Tags: java, opencv, javacv, marvin-framework

I'm trying to work on how to activate webcam and capture videos with marvin framework. i insalled javacv and opencv but i still get an exception. i don't know if it's due to a problem of versions of opencv and javacv or what.
hope u guys can help.

Here's the exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniopencv_core in java.library.path
```

and this message too:

```
SETUP: Setting up device 0
SETUP: HP Webcam
SETUP: Couldn't find preview pin using SmartTee
SETUP: Default Format is set to 640 by 360 
SETUP: trying requested format RGB24 @ 640 by 480
SETUP: Capture callback set
SETUP: Device is setup and ready to capture.
```

'

here's my code:

```
public class SimpleVideoTest extends JFrame implements Runnable{

private MarvinVideoInterface    videoAdapter;
private MarvinImage             image;
private MarvinImagePanel        videoPanel;

public SimpleVideoTest(){
    super("Simple Video Test");

    // Create the VideoAdapter and connect to the camera
    MarvinVideoInterface  videoAdapter = new MarvinJavaCVAdapter();
    try {
        videoAdapter.connect(0);
    } catch (MarvinVideoInterfaceException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Create VideoPanel
    videoPanel = new MarvinImagePanel();
    add(videoPanel);

    // Start the thread for requesting the video frames 
    new Thread(this).start();

    setSize(800,600);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleVideoTest t = new SimpleVideoTest();
    t.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

 @Override
public void run() {
    while(true){
        // Request a video frame and set into the VideoPanel
        try {
            image = videoAdapter.getFrame();
        } catch (MarvinVideoInterfaceException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        videoPanel.setImage(image);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how exactly are you launching your java application?

openCV has a native library (see [this doc](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d52/tutorial_java_dev_intro.html), refers to libopencv_java*.so/dll)
that native library needs to be on the classpath for the JVM you are launching.

see [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550571/loading-jni-lib-on-mac-os-x) for details on how