# How to implement Asprise OCR Library

Tags: java, ocr

Could someone please tell me how to implement the Asprise OCR library into my java program.
I'm using Eclipse and I know how to import the .jar but as soon as I want to run my program it gives me errors about a .dll file that's missing.

Comment: You need to leave more details, such as the text of the error message.

Comment: I fixed it now, just didn't copy the .dll's to the right place!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, I just had to copy the .dll that came with the .jar to System32.
If you don't want to add them to System 32 just add them to your workspace and use

```
'System.load("dll_name_without_.dll_at_the_end");'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, [Asprise OCR library for Java](http://asprise.com/royalty-free-library/java-ocr-api-overview.html) automatically handles the native library files since version 5.0.

Java offers two methods to load libraries and a good explanation is here 
[Difference between System.load() and System.loadLibrary in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016391/difference-between-system-load-and-system-loadlibrary-in-java)