# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when i load a jar .

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, classloader, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I ' m programming with JSE  and i'm loading a jar (that i do ) with another java program  .
The problem is in classLoader of java virtual machine i think .
i said that beacuse i   tried to exec the file jar with java -jar "file.jar" and  it runs  .
I'm using xubuntu with eclipse.
In eclipse, i have 2 project  that respectively are the first software that loads jar and the jar software .
To export the jar file i use the wizard "Export -> jar ecc...." 
How can i resolve this problem?

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /media/sda4/so_project/proj/example/first.jar: /media/sda4/so_project/proj/example/first.jar: invalid ELF header (Possible cause: endianness mismatch)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1939)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1825)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:792)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1059)
    at it.unicam.project.Binterpreter.getClassHandle(Binterpreter.java:170)
    at it.unicam.project.Binterpreter.(Binterpreter.java:100)
    at it.unicam.project.Test.main(Test.java:12)

Comment: invalid ELF header could be 32/64 bit mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're running a 32bit JVM on a 64bit platform

Comment: I tried to install in my pc the 64 bit jvm but i cannot install it beacuse the os doesn't allow it .
Are you sure that the problem is this ? :S

Comment: Not sure but you can check the 32/64 architecture of each environment:See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062020/how-can-i-tell-if-im-running-in-64-bit-jvm-or-32-bit-jvm

Comment: So the two environments are 32 bits. Could be an eclipse thing (you said that the jar is created wit Eclipse export utility), have you tried to build the jar from the console? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Comment: i tried with console (without consider  some problem with manifest ) i have the same problem . I tried to download this jar http://dasha.ics.hawaii.edu/~johnson/613f99/modules/04/psae.jar and i called first.jar but the same problem .... :S

Comment: But this jar works nicely in my computer:    C:\Users\w7\Downloads>java -jar psae.jar hello
Hello World hello       Do you have the JAVA_HOME variable correctly set?

Comment: i tried the same command and then it works but if i try to load with System.load jvm generates the error that i post  above.

Comment: Ok, have you tried System.loadLibrary instead of System.load? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016391/difference-between-system-load-and-system-loadlibrary-in-java

Comment: no beacuse it says : 
"The difference is there in the API documentation. system.loadLibrary(String libname) lets you load from the default path -- The Java library path." The file jar isn't in a default path.
And if i try to do that returns me this error :
http://pastebin.com/3S6QCXzQ

Comment: Just one thing. Are you trying to load a jar with System.load ? System.load is for loading dynamic libraries, no jars. In order to user a jar just put it in the classpath and call it.

Comment: emhm.. yes  ,i find this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194698/how-to-load-a-jar-file-at-runtime to load jar at runtime, thank you for you help.