# Running a jar in a computer java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError lwjgl.dll in another computer

Tags: java, jar, lwjgl, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I created an aplication, and in my computer, the jar is running without any problems. I tried to run it in another pc, it doesn't do ANYTHING, like, at all. And then, i tried the same jar in another pc (a 3rd pc if you want so see it that way), there, the jar runs without a problem. So i came back to the second one, and tried to run it from the command line, and it's giving me this error:

"Exception in thead "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: can't load library: 
C:\Users\hectlr\lib\natives\lwjgl.dll"

What really caught my attention, is that in the other computers, works, but it's not using that path, i mean, the firs one, mi pc it's c:\users\hectorhammett... and the other pc it's c:\users\pedro... in the pedro one, i don't have anything about java, it's a recently formated pc, i just installed java and it's working... any ideas?

Comment: Are you running jar from a batch file or just double clicking on it?

Comment: Just double clicking it.

Comment: When i did the same, jar automatically extracts the dll files that are being used in the jar's folder. Then i copy all in a rar then extract them and they works. Maybe there must be path variable in the jar export settings.

Comment: Also i have to say, i made the jar in netbeans, and changed the manifest, and it works. But not in all pc. HELP!

Comment: maybe look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683357/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-when-i-load-a-jar?rq=1

Comment: It's not the OS, because it runs in my pc (64 bits) and my Friends pc (32 bits), the second one, it's 32.

Answer (score 0):

This problem generally occurs when your jar trying to use native library of operating system.In windows it is "LWJGL.DLL".  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError occurs if the JVM cannot find this file. try to find the existence of this file in machine 2 where your jar file is not working and try to add them to path if they does not exists.

Comment: I'm sorry man, i didn't quite get your comment. Just to put something else, i've never put that path. I mean, i have no idea why the jar it's looking in that path.

Comment: May be this helps you    http://www.coderanch.com/t/377174/java/java/java-library-path

Comment: I don't get it, why is it looking in the users library!. I have it in the project folder, under native folder, why it looks there!.

Answer (score 0):

```
Exception in thead "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
can't load library: C:\Users\hectlr\lib\natives\lwjgl.dll
```

means that the target computer doesn't find the dll at the specified place, **or**, it means that the dll is not compatible.

Check if you can find the dll in `C:\Users\hectlr\lib\natives\`, then check if the dll is the good one (x86 vs. x64).