# How to solve the shared library import issue on Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I have some shared libraries, may be `libaaa.so`, `libbbb.so`, `libccc.so`.

1. `libaaa.so` only compiled on `armeabi` ARCH
2. `libbbb.so` compiled on `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a`
3. and `libccc.so` compiled on both ARCHs(`x86`, `arm64`, `mips` ...)

At present, i have to copy the `libaaa.so` into `armeabi-v7a`, `arm64-v8a` ... folders, otherwise, cashes will be raised.

How to avoid the extra copy?

Comment: Refer http://ph0b.com/android-abis-and-so-files/. From that page "There is a dead simple but not well-known important rule to follow when dealing with .so files.

You should provide libraries optimized for each ABIs if possible, but it’s all in or nothing: you shall not mix. You have to provide the full set of the libraries you’re using in each ABI folder." So it seems that you will need to put your so files in all folders for different architectures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `System.load()` instead of `System.loadLibrary()`.

The difference had been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016391/difference-between-system-load-and-system-loadlibrary-in-java).