# Java application does not execute on other devices, UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, batch-file, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have a Java application that uses the JFlashPlayer libraries.  I can run it on my system, via a batch file, with no problems - it runs perfectly, as expected.  The `.bat` file is as follows:

```
java -classpath jflashplayer.jar;commons-io-2.4.jar;bin flashPresentationController
```

As mentioned previously, the application runs without issue on my computer, but when trying to run it on another computer, the following error occurs:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.jpackages.jflashplayer....
```

I was having this exact same error when trying to package the application in an executable JAR file, but the batch file always worked without error.  How can I remedy this issue so that I can either a) use the existing batch file to run the application, or b) package the whole application in an executable JAR file?

I've tried changing paths of the included libraries and files, as per the suggestions of other posts relating to UnsatisfiedLinkError, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.html), you will see this:

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine cannot find an appropriate native-language definition of a method declared native.

This means that jflashplayer has some native dependencies.

Edit: maybe you should check out this: [java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError in jflashplayer — getOSVersion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026375/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-in-jflashplayer-getosversion)

Comment: I have viewed the JavaDoc before, and have read the same line.  I am not a seasoned pro when it comes to Java, and so I am not sure how to include/modify said native dependencies.  

As for the SO link you provided, I've also viewed it previously and found it to be of no help.  The entire code is written, I am not interested in switching from JFlashPlayer, but rather getting it to work properly.  

The batch file works on my system, but the executable JAR does not (gives me the exact same error as in the post).  How do I fix the dependencies so that I can make the JAR file or use the batch?

Comment: I am using Eclipse to build/compile the application.

Comment: There is not even a website for jflashplayer so I'm just guessing. Did you install FlashPlayer on the other computer?

Comment: Yep.  JFlashPlayer has been discontinued, but it is still available to download.