# Java Library Path in Eclipse - Add dll library to multiple jars at once?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have used the accepted answer provided to the question ["How to set the java.library.path from Eclipse?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957700/how-to-set-the-java-library-path-from-eclipse) for setting the library path for a specific jar.

In my case, I have about 10 third party jars and each jar depends on the same set of dlls, but I need to do this process for each jar. I can do this manually, but is there any way to do this for more than one jar at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, manually editing the project's `.classpath` file might gain you a bit of efficiency. When I set the location of a JAR's native library, the following entry is added to my `.classpath` file:

```
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="path/to/library.jar" sourcepath="/path/to/src">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.CLASSPATH_ATTR_LIBRARY_PATH_ENTRY" value="path/to/native/library.dll"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

You might manually set up the first JAR (via the Eclipse UI), close Eclipse and copy/paste the generated classpath entries in `.classpath` with the appropriate modifications, and then restart Eclipse.