# Start Tomcat from eclipse(project has c library)

Tags: eclipse, tomcat6

I have a java project in eclipse which are using tomcat. This project has some dependency over c library. When i start tomcat using startup.sh it is working fine but when i try to start tomcat from eclipse it gives me error while starting itself. Is there any way i can start tomcat from eclipse as if i start it from startup.sh, i not able to set any breakpoint.

Comment: Could you please provide the error message from eclipse's embedded tomcat ?

Comment: It actually says could not initialize for class which uses that c library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any of your Java code is using a native (C) library, that library (.dll or .so file) must be included in the path specified by the Java system property java.library.path. There's a few ways to go about doing that, but this seems like the most logical: [How to set the java.library.path from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957700/how-to-set-the-java-library-path-from-eclipse)

Comment: my problem gets resolved after adding it as vm parameter. Some one has done the same thing in link provided by you.