# How to Convert Mp4 to mpg using Xuggler

Tags: windows-7

I am trying to convert a video from mpg to mp4 using Xuggler But When It comes to read the old file or write the new file I get the following error  What Can I do for That .Please
Help.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:    org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibrary.<clinit>(JNILibrary.java:42)
at com.xuggle.ferry.FerryJNI.<clinit>(FerryJNI.java:14)
at com.xuggle.ferry.Ferry.<clinit>(Ferry.java:25)
at com.xuggle.xuggler.XugglerJNI.<clinit>(XugglerJNI.java:19)
at com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer.<clinit>(IContainer.java:1622)
at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.<init>(MediaReader.java:137)
at com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory.makeReader(ToolFactory.java:77)
at Maind.Main$HandlerClass3.actionPerformed(Main.java:1055)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)

at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)

at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)

at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 44 more
```

What is the problem with that?Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324478/how-do-i-have-to-install-configure-xuggle-to-not-get-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror/11476592#11476592

Answer (score 2):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibrary.<clinit>(JNILibrary.java:42)
```

It means that you need to put in your classpath the archive: `slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar` (or newest version).