# ERROR com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader - Could not load library: xuggle-xuggler; version: 3;

Tags: java, xuggler

I have recently downloaded a code for, **Xuggler Tutorial: Frames Capture and Video Creation** from [this link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/xuggler-tutorial-frames-capture-video.html/comment-page-1/#comment-4336), I have added all the **.jar** files in my project which are required to run this code but, When I am running this code then I am getting Error:

Here is my code:

```
package xug;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaReader;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaListenerAdapter;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.event.IVideoPictureEvent;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.Global;

public class VideoThumbnailsExample {

    public static final double SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES = 10;
    private static final String inputFilename = "e:/low_light.mp4";
    private static final String outputFilePrefix = "e:/Frames/processedImages";
    // The video stream index, used to ensure we display frames from one and
    // only one video stream from the media container.
    private static int mVideoStreamIndex = -1;
    // Time of last frame write
    private static long mLastPtsWrite = Global.NO_PTS;
    public static final long MICRO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES =
            (long) (Global.DEFAULT_PTS_PER_SECOND * SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        IMediaReader mediaReader = ToolFactory.makeReader(inputFilename);

        // stipulate that we want BufferedImages created in BGR 24bit color space
        mediaReader.setBufferedImageTypeToGenerate(BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);

        mediaReader.addListener(new ImageSnapListener());

        // read out the contents of the media file and
        // dispatch events to the attached listener
        while (mediaReader.readPacket() == null) ;

    }

    private static class ImageSnapListener extends MediaListenerAdapter {

        public void onVideoPicture(IVideoPictureEvent event) {

            if (event.getStreamIndex() != mVideoStreamIndex) {
                // if the selected video stream id is not yet set, go ahead an
                // select this lucky video stream
                if (mVideoStreamIndex == -1) {
                    mVideoStreamIndex = event.getStreamIndex();
                } // no need to show frames from this video stream
                else {
                    return;
                }
            }

            // if uninitialized, back date mLastPtsWrite to get the very first frame
            if (mLastPtsWrite == Global.NO_PTS) {
                mLastPtsWrite = event.getTimeStamp() - MICRO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES;
            }

            // if it's time to write the next frame
            if (event.getTimeStamp() - mLastPtsWrite
                    >= MICRO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES) {

                String outputFilename = dumpImageToFile(event.getImage());

                // indicate file written
                double seconds = ((double) event.getTimeStamp())
                        / Global.DEFAULT_PTS_PER_SECOND;
                System.out.printf(
                        "at elapsed time of %6.3f seconds wrote: %s\n",
                        seconds, outputFilename);

                // update last write time
                mLastPtsWrite += MICRO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES;
            }

        }

        private String dumpImageToFile(BufferedImage image) {
            try {
                String outputFilename = outputFilePrefix
                        + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
                ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(outputFilename));
                return outputFilename;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I am getting following error in this.

```
[main] ERROR com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader - Could not load library: xuggle-xuggler; version: 3; Visit http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/faq/ to find common solutions to this problem
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no xuggle-xuggler in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader.loadLibrary0(JNILibraryLoader.java:265)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader.loadLibrary(JNILibraryLoader.java:168)
    at com.xuggle.xuggler.XugglerJNI.<clinit>(XugglerJNI.java:19)
    at com.xuggle.xuggler.Global.<clinit>(Global.java:238)
    at xug.VideoThumbnailsExample.<clinit>(VideoThumbnailsExample.java:28)
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
```

Please explain why **Class-Loader** is unable to load the **.jar** file.

Comment: Looks like the native compiled library (.so, .dll or .dylib) can't be found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have is that the native libraries that Xuggle uses cannot be found. I suspect that there is a conflict in your classpath.

If by "all the jars" you mean the jars in the download page, you are not supposed to download all of them. At the [Xuggler downloads page](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/downloads) it says that either you download the `xuggle‑xuggler.jar` that contains the native libraries for all operating systems or you choose a specific architecture.

On an attempt to run the example you link to, I have done the following:

- Downloaded [xuggle‑xuggler.jar](http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/5.2/xuggle-xuggler-5.2.jar) (v.5.2). I didn't use maven, so as per the instrunctions at the download page I opened the [Xuggle POM file](http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/5.2/xuggle-xuggler-5.2.pom) to check and get the dependencies using the specific versions.
- Using a little help from google those dependencies are: [slf4j-1.6.4](http://www.slf4j.org/dist/slf4j-1.6.4.zip),  [commons-cli 1.1](http://archive.apache.org/dist/commons/cli/binaries/commons-cli-1.1.zip), [logback 1.0](http://logback.qos.ch/dist/logback-1.0.0.zip), (contains two of the required jars), [xuggle-utils 1.20](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/xuggle/xuggle-utils-1.20.688.jar.zip) and `junit` which you can ignore.
  After downloading you can find inside the zip files the 5 jars (`slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar, commons-cli-1.1.jar, logback-core-1.0.0.jar, logback-classic-1.0.0.jar, xuggle-utils-1.20.688.jar`) described in the POM file that are the dependencies of the `xuggle‑xuggler.jar`.
- Create a project in your favourite IDE (I use Eclipse) import those 6 jar files to your project and you are good to go.

Following the procedure above I was able to run your test program succesfully in a Windows machine.

I hope that helps.

Comment: can you please help for the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21672099/exception-error-com-xuggle-ferry-jnilibraryloader-could-not-load-library-oc

Comment: these can links are broken , can you please update your answer

Comment: @Jaggz the links are broken but there is no updated answer. If you visit [xuggler's github page](https://github.com/artclarke/xuggle-xuggler) you will see that it is now deprecated and the author suggests to use [Humble video](https://github.com/artclarke/humble-video) instead

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the best solution is to use Xuggler 5.4 with maven due to [How do I have to install/configure Xuggle to not get an UnsatisfiedLinkError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324478/how-do-i-have-to-install-configure-xuggle-to-not-get-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror)

Comment: Using xuggle 5.4 with maven in Linux but getting the same error: Could not load library: xuggle; version: 5 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no xuggle in java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib:/lib:/usr/lib. Mac (dev) is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Following c.s.'s answer this ended out working for me:

- Instead of xuggle‑xuggler.jar use [xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar](http://www.atech-software.com/nexus/content/groups/public/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/5.4/xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar) (google the name if link is broken)
- Instead of xuggle-utils-1.20.688.jar use [com.xuggle.utils-1.22.jar](https://repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/liferay/com.xuggle.utils/1.22/com.xuggle.utils-1.22.jar)
- Create a project, import the 6 jars and run this to test:

  ```
  import com.xuggle.xuggler.ICodec;
  import com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory;
  import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaWriter;
  import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
  import java.io.File;
  import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

  public class XuggleTest {

      private static int idx = 1;
      private static final int WIDTH = 500;
      private static final int HEIGHT = 500;
      private static final int NFRAMES = 200;

      public static void main(String[] arguments) {

          // Create writer
          IMediaWriter writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter("output.mp4");
          writer.addVideoStream(0, 0, ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_MPEG4, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
          long ms = 15; // ms per frame

          for (int i = 0; i < NFRAMES; i++) {

              BufferedImage frame = convert(getFrame());
              long time = i * ms;
              writer.encodeVideo(0, frame, time, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

              idx++;
          }
          System.out.println("Finished writing file: " + System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + writer.getUrl());

          writer.close();
      }

      private static BufferedImage convert(BufferedImage value) {
          // Convert data type
          BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(value.getWidth(), value.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
          result.getGraphics().drawImage(value, 0, 0, null);
          return result;
      }

      private static BufferedImage getFrame() {
          // Create image frame
          BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
          img.createGraphics().fillRoundRect(idx, idx, idx, idx, 10, 10);
          return img;
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Just download the xuggler 3.4 exe in Windows OS and add the jar file
1) xuggle-xuggler-arch-x86_64-w64-mingw32.jar you get this jar from the following link:
https://files.liferay.com/mirrors/xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/5.4/