# Could not load library: xuggle; version: 5; Using POM

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, xuggler, xuggle

I'm attempting to use Xuggle and when trying to deploy, I'm getting the following error, below that is my POM file.  Hopefully someone can tell me what I'm missing

```
 13:55:34.965 [main] ERROR com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader - Could not load library: xuggle; version: 5; Visit http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/faq/ to find common solutions to this problem
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no xuggle in java.library.path  
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)  
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)  
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)  
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader.loadLibrary0(JNILibraryLoader.java:268)  
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader.loadLibrary(JNILibraryLoader.java:171)  
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibrary.load(JNILibrary.java:161)  
    at com.xuggle.ferry.FerryJNI.<clinit>(FerryJNI.java:16)  
    at com.xuggle.ferry.Ferry.<clinit>(Ferry.java:25)  
    at com.xuggle.xuggler.XugglerJNI.<clinit>(XugglerJNI.java:19)  
    at com.xuggle.xuggler.Global.<clinit>(Global.java:238)  
    at com.ngc.h264.H264.<clinit>(H264.java:23)
```

---

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>h264</groupId>
    <artifactId>h264</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>xuggle repo</id>
            <url>http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jcodec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcodec</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.6-3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xuggle</groupId>
            <artifactId>xuggle-xuggler</artifactId>
            <version>5.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Additionally, looking at my Maven Dependencies I have the following:

1. jcodec-0.1.6-3.jar
2. xuggle-xuggler-5.2.jar
3. slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
4. commons-cli-1.1.jar
5. logback-core-1.0.0.jar
6. logback-classic-1.0.0.jar

Thoughts?

Comment: It's telling you to put the native code for xuggle in java.library.path. Do it.

Comment: According to their documentation it's not required.  Just found on their blogsite I can upgrade from 5.2 to 5.4 and now it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to their blog site, migrating to 5.2 to 5.4 fixes this issue.

Tested and confirmed

Comment: i am using 5.4 still the same issue.

Comment: if still not working check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077307/error-com-xuggle-ferry-jnilibraryloader-could-not-load-library-xuggle-xuggler