# Making xuggler work with maven

Tags: java, maven, xuggler

I am trying to work with `xuggler` with maven.

I included the dependency and repository adds from the `xuggler` site: [xuggle download](http://www.xuggle.com/downloads).

But I had some additional problems and added the dependencies for `slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar`, `commons-cli-1.1.jar`, `logback-core-1.0.0.jar`, `logback-classic-1.0.0.jar` as mentioned in this answer [ERROR com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077307/error-com-xuggle-ferry-jnilibraryloader-could-not-load-library-xuggle-xuggler). In the above I did not include the `xuggle-utils-1.20.688.jar` since I could not find a maven dependency for this (do I need this anyway).

Now the error I am getting is `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no xuggle in java.library.path` which if I am interpreting correctly mean the system cannot find `xuggle` library? Since I am using win7 that means something like `xuggle.dll` or `libxuggle.dll` I guess. So am I suppose to download another jar (like the `xuggle-utils-1.20.688.jar` mentioned before for example)?

For completeness the example I am trying to compile is in here [xuggle example](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/introduction-xuggler-video-manipulation.html).

Do I have to declare something to the `java.library.path` (which I have no idea how to do it)?

Answer (score 3):

OK, I have found the solution to be to switch to a newer version of `xuggler` as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317192/could-not-load-library-xuggle-version-5-using-pom).

The interesting part is that this blog here `http://blog.xuggle.com/` which is semi-official states that even since v5.2 of `xuggler` the need for downloading multiple jars etc has been eliminated. Probably not.

I also had to use the latest version of `logback-core` (1.1.2) to make it work around a new exception that was thrown.