# Adding xuggler dependency gives error

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, xuggler

I want to generate single thumbnail image from video so I'm using xuggler. I tried to add its dependency and repository.

```
<repository>
    <id>xuggle repo</id>
    <url>http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/</url>
</repository>

<dependency>
   <groupId>xuggle</groupId>
   <artifactId>xuggle-xuggler</artifactId>
   <version>5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

But after adding the dependency I get error 
**Missing artifact xuggle:xuggle-xuggler:jar:5.2**.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317192/could-not-load-library-xuggle-version-5-using-pom)  link I even changed the version but it still gives me error. 
Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: It doesn't seem anyone is maintaining Xuggler any more. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37696583/xuggler-repository-link-broken/37924763#37924763

Comment: @Ben so is there some other option available in place of Xuggler?

Answer (score 18):

No one is maintaining Xuggler anymore, but there is still a saved repository.
Try using this repository for xuggler: https://files.liferay.com/mirrors/xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/ (Version 5.4 **ONLY**)

#### Code:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>xuggle repo</id>
    <url>https://files.liferay.com/mirrors/xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>xuggle</groupId>
    <artifactId>xuggle-xuggler</artifactId>
    <version>5.4</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 8):

On Maven Repository, we can read:

link: [Xuggle maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/5.4)

> Note: this artifact it located at Dcm4Che repository
>   (http://www.dcm4che.org/maven2/)

Add this repository instead "files.liferay.com" repository

```
    <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>dcm4che repository</id>
        <url>http://www.dcm4che.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

EDIT: Alternative on **Liferay's repository**

[Liferay's thirs party repo](https://repository.liferay.com/nexus/index.html#view-repositories;third-party~browsestorage)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.liferay</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.xuggle.xuggler</artifactId>
    <version>5.4</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That website is dead

Comment: Maybe, but it's reference on Maven Repository atm. Any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

java 1.8

```
porn.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>VideoInformation</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <repositories>

        <repository>
            <id>xuggle repo</id>
            <url>http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.11</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xuggle</groupId>
            <artifactId>xuggle-xuggler</artifactId>
            <version>5.4</version>
        </dependency>

</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Xuggler main repo is not maintained but I maintain a fork since 7 years to add support to mobile (Android and iOS) and to be up to date with new versions of FFmpeg. You can use this artifact

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>xuggle</groupId>
  <artifactId>xuggle-xuggler-server-all</artifactId>
  <version>5.7.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

You can configure the Maven repository with

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>olivier-ayache-xuggler</id> 
    <url>https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/olivier-ayache/xuggler/maven/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```