# Xuggler Repository Link Broken

Tags: java, maven, svn, xuggler

In my JAVA application, i am using Xuggler for ScreenCapture and other functionality. Now its a maven project so i put Xuggler as dependency in Pom.xml as told in this [Link](http://www.xuggle.com/downloads).

Now few days ago i cleaned my system, so when i again imported my project, now it is showing "Missing artifact xuggle:xuggle-xuggler:jar:5.4". Though in pom file, repository link is there. I explored more and found out that http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/5.4/xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar is showing 404 error(Not Found).

Now my whole JAVA Application requires Xuggler, so can anyone please share me current working link from where i can download "xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar" or any other method(s) so that in future i don't face such problem again.

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem anyone is maintaining Xuggler any more: the [last blog post](https://blog.xuggle.com/) says "Xuggler development is on hiatus.  Probably permanently."

If you are good with Maven and suchlike you might be able to build Xuggler yourself. [The source code is available from the Google Code archive](https://code.google.com/archive/p/xuggle/source).

Answer (score 7):

from http://www.xuggle.com/downloads
change the url:
  `<url>https://files.liferay.com/mirrors/xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/</url>`