# Exception: "ERROR com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader - Could not load library" occur

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, video-processing

I read about [library-xuggle-xuggler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077307/error-com-xuggle-ferry-jnilibraryloader-could-not-load-library-xuggle-xuggler) from Stackoverflow and I have added the below jars as

1. slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar,
2. commons-cli-1.1.jar,
3. logback-core-1.0.0.jar,
4. logback-classic-1.0.0.jar,
5. xuggle-utils-1.20.688.jar,
6. xuggle‑xuggler-5.2.jar

sequentially in java class path(order and export tab) as mentioned in the post. But unfortunately i am still getting exception bellow yet:

```
14:14:00.941 [main] ERROR com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader - Could not load library: xuggle; version: 5; Visit http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/faq/ to find common solutions to this problem
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no xuggle in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader.loadLibrary0(JNILibraryLoader.java:268)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader.loadLibrary(JNILibraryLoader.java:171)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibrary.load(JNILibrary.java:161)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.FerryJNI.<clinit>(FerryJNI.java:16)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNIMemoryManager.<clinit>(JNIMemoryManager.java:871)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.<clinit>(MediaWriter.java:119)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory.makeWriter(ToolFactory.java:149)
    at com.java.concate.CallConcatenate.main(CallConcatenate.java:24)
```

Please help me to solve this problem. Is there any dependency for using this jars.

Comment: Did you "Visit http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/faq/ to find common solutions to this problem "?

Comment: I have visited now. But can,t understand it. This page shows "These routes have been tried, in this order :

    GET       /@documentation/cheatsheet/{category}             PlayDocumentation.cheatSheet
    GET       /@documentation/modules/{module}/files/{name}     PlayDocumentation.file ". I think it is not found response.

Comment: Probably a long shot but in the tab "Order and Export" please make sure that the `xuggler.jar` is first in the list among the rest of your jars. If this does not work can you please add your environment settings as reported by `System.getProperties()` ?

Comment: I tried in both way by putting the xuggle-xuggler.jar in head or tail. But get same result. Is there any .dll file problem that system can not find?

Comment: Where I have to add .dll files? what are the names of dll for it?

Comment: The dll files are inside the `xuggler.jar`. Normally java tries to load them from the path specified by the `java.library.path` system property but xuggler overrides this behaviour. You can check the [source](https://github.com/artclarke/xuggle-xuggler/blob/master/src/com/xuggle/ferry/JNILibraryLoader.java) to investigate what is wrong in your system

Answer (score 2):

the best way to fix it is using Xuggler 5.4 with maven according to [How do I have to install/configure Xuggle to not get an UnsatisfiedLinkError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324478/how-do-i-have-to-install-configure-xuggle-to-not-get-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror)