# Eclipse doesn't copy my native libs

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, native-code

I'm trying to build a plugin that contains some native libraries.
The project has the standard maven layout but is currently not configured as a maven project for m2e. (I will do this after eclipse can build my plugin)

I put my native libs under *src/main/resources* and configured eclipse the following way:

*build.properties*:

```
source.. = src/main/java/
output.. = target/classes/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
       src/main/resources/libdb_java-5.0.so,\
       src/main/resources/libdb-5.0.so,\
       .
```

BuildPath:
[image: My BuildPath]

But eclipse doesn't copy my native libs from *src/main/resources* to *target/classes*.
Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to manually add the *src/main/resources* folder as a class folder to your project under the *Libraries* tab to have the native libs available at runtime.

For the resulting plugin you should check the exported plugin but i think they should be contained there.

Comment: Hi. Yes you're right. Adding src/main/resources as a "class folder" works. You could also add the directory as a "source folder". Thanks. Now I got another problem. Eclipse seems to set the library path to the project directory instead to the specified output directory. Do you know how to change this?

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand what you mean, I guess you are referring to what you find under Runtime Information on the Build tab. The library found there (.) is defined in the last build.properties entry of bin.includes shown above.

Comment: I mean that eclipse can't find my native libraries copied under target/classes. If I copy them in the project directory then they can be loaded. I would like to change the library path to target/classes so eclipse can load my libraries.

Comment: Ok, I tried setting the native location like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957700/how-to-set-the-java-library-path-from-eclipse

But eclipse doesn't change my library path. Does it matter that the plugin containing the native libs is actual a fragment bundle?

Comment: That's strange. The error comes from the
Bundle-NativeCode: libdb_java-5.0.so; osname="linux"; processor="x86", libdb-5.0.so; osname="linux"; processor="x86" directive in my manifest. When I remove the line then it works. o.O