# How do I add external libraries to java.library.path in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, path

My first time playing around with JOGL, and I get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gluegen-rt in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.jogamp.gluegen.runtime.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:117)
    at com.jogamp.gluegen.runtime.NativeLibLoader.access$000(NativeLibLoader.java:51)
    at com.jogamp.gluegen.runtime.NativeLibLoader$1.run(NativeLibLoader.java:70)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.jogamp.gluegen.runtime.NativeLibLoader.loadGlueGenRT(NativeLibLoader.java:68)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JVMUtil.<clinit>(JVMUtil.java:56)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.<clinit>(GLProfile.java:1145)
    at tut.Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

I looked around and found nothing on how to add gluegen-rt or anything else to java.library.path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the answer at "[How to set the java.library.path from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/958074/751158)".  Basically, there is a project configuration for "Native library location".

Comment: Would you mind showing us a screenshot of the Eclipse configuration?  I'm guessing something has to be slightly off...