# Oracle JDBC Driver Error on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, oracle, jdbc, timezone

I am trying to execute a query using a stored procedure in Eclipse, but I keep getting this error and I am not sure what I am missing to be able to execute the query.

The query works in the actual server the code would be run on, but I am trying to mimic that environment in Eclipse (That being said I know the problem is not in the code, but I am clearly missing a dependency or something? I am not sure).

The error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.t2cSetSessionTimeZone(JLjava/lang/String;)
```

Here is what I have in my eclipse project:

Libraries:

- Activation.jar
- mail.jar
- ojdbc5.jar
- rt.jar
- JRE System Library[J2SE-1.4]

Order and Export:

- ojdbc5.jar
- rt.jar
- Activation.jar
- mail.jar
- src
- JRE System Library[J2SE-1.4]

Also, Compiler info:

- Java Compiler - J2SE-1.4
- generated .class file compatibility - 1.2
- Source compatibility - 1.3

Not sure what other information I should provide..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember getting the `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` when a dll that should have been on the system path is not present.

In my case there was JAVA code which relied on some native C++ code residing in a dll. Whenever the dll was absent from the classpath the error would be observed.

If this strikes a bell, try adding the required dll as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957700/how-to-set-the-java-library-path-from-eclipse) answer explains.

**Update**

Try this :

> Add C:\app\\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2\jdk\bin to the PATH
>   environment variable.

Also, check [**this**](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2294381) thread for further clues. The OP on this thread solved his problem by doing the above.

**Update 2**

It seems that a specific version of the driver jars maybe required. Do you have the Oracle Client installed ? Take a look at **[this](http://www.progtown.com/topic529131-problem-with-jdbc-oci-oracle-11g-r2-exception.html)** (unfortunately, badly translated) thread. Scroll to the bottom to see how that OP fixed this same problem.

Comment: I tried setting the path to the jdbc folder in the oracle client on my windows machine.. perhaps I need the server version since I think that is what is installed on the actual server.. I will keep trying different places and see if I can fix it. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: I think the problem is I have client version or Oracle and the server has server version or Oracle.  I will try to get the necessary files, but it seems like this is a class path issue. thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score -2):

Problem could also be bacuase of the 'thin' and 'oci' driver declaration. Change the driver name from 'oci' to 'thin' will fix the issue