# load java native file lib

Tags: java, native, loadlibrary, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I would like to use some native files and use some files out of an android project. I need this files for my own java project and need to import the lib.

I am trying to load the lib with:

```
static
{
    System.loadLibrary("mrclient_java");
}
```

The lib file "libmrclient_java.so" is in this folder: "/libs/armeabi/".

When I run the project following error appears:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mrclient_java in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
```

I dont know how to configure the CLASSPATH or whatever to solve this problem.
I am not using android for this project. The android project itself runs perfectly.

EDIT:

I found this Question: [How to set the java.library.path from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957700/how-to-set-the-java-library-path-from-eclipse), but the same error still appear.

Comment: `no mrclient_java in java.library.path` So does java.library.path point to /libs/armeabi?

Comment: Yes thats correct but I doenst know how to set this path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `java.library.path` to your command line that runs java. Something like the following:

`java -cp YOURCLASSPATH -Djava.library.path=/libs/armeabi/ com.compnay.Main`

Classpath is for loading java classes only. Library path is for loading native libraries.

Comment: Can you set java.library.path on runtime?

Comment: (Btw I am using Windows and Eclipse) Is the end of your command correct? Do I have to replace that one with my package name or something?