# How to load native library to play framework

Tags: java, opencv, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

I have been  trying to develop a play framework application. i am using opencv (.jar + native library) in this application. When i try to run the application with

```
play start
```

command the application runs fine and perfect. when tried with

```
play run
```

and it needs to access the opencv methods it gets a runtime error saying

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.imread_0(Ljava/lang/String;I)J
    at org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.imread_0(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.imread(Highgui.java:299)
    at com.allspark.scanners.LabelImScanner.readLabel(LabelImScanner.java:39)
    at com.allspark.controllers.imageController.uploadLabel(imageController.java:55)
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$19$$anonfun$apply$19.apply(routes_routing.scala:289)
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$19$$anonfun$apply$19.apply(routes_routing.scala:289)
```

then I tried to run the application in production mode then everything works fine.
I need to know how to load the native library to play application runs in development mode.
This issue already discussed in followings:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/A3cL3dkD70I
https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2212
[How to include native library (JNI) in play 2.1 RC2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360143/how-to-include-native-library-jni-in-play-2-1-rc2)

but unfortunately nothing works for development mode application.
I am using play famework 2.2.0 and opencv-246. If anyone can give support that would be great help.Thank you.
Appreciate your help

Comment: please any one have an idea. :( please help me

Comment: joining the question

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

1.
Create a /lib folder in you play project and then play clean and  compile (SBT will take care of every thing)

2.

```
cp  opencv-2412.jar /your-play-project/target/native_libraries/64bits/
cp  ibopencv_java2412.dylib  /your-play-project/target/native_libraries/64bits/
```

then play clean and compile

Comment: Thank you .. I will give it a try