# How to use Eclipse Indigo with Java communication API

Tags: java, serial-port

I am working with Java communication API in Eclipse. This is my sample program to get all available ports for communication but the program exits because `CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers()` doesn't return anything. `Enumeration  enu_ports` is null and program exits.

Steps I have done:

- I have connected my smart hoper to the host.
- Put win32com.dll file system32 folder and also added in eclipse project
- Add javax.comm.properties file in eclipse project
- Added com.jar to the build path my system is 32 bit and os is windows 7

If any step is incorrect please provide steps to use Eclipse Indigo with Java communication API.

```
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier;

class GetAvailableComPorts {

    public static void getComPorts(){
        String     port_type;
        Enumeration  enu_ports  = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

        while (enu_ports.hasMoreElements()) {
            CommPortIdentifier port_identifier = (CommPortIdentifier) enu_ports.nextElement();

            switch(port_identifier.getPortType()){
                case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL:
                    port_type   =   "Serial";
                    break;
                case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_PARALLEL:
                    port_type   =   "Parallel";
                    break;

                default:
                    port_type   =   "Unknown";
                    break;
            }

            System.out.println("Port : "+port_identifier.getName() +" Port type : "+port_type);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getComPorts();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem most certainly isn't related to Eclipse. What serial library are you using? It doesn't seem to be RXTX. Did you try alternative libraries, like [PureJavacomm](https://github.com/nyholku/purejavacomm), or [NrJavaSerial](http://code.google.com/p/nrjavaserial/)? Does that resolve your issue?

Comment: The original JavaComm API is rather old and no longer supported, you might want to investigate alternatives, like RXTX?

Comment: Aside that: did you add the native library (the DLL) to your project? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957700/how-to-set-the-java-library-path-from-eclipse for details on how to do that...