# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: sample.HelloWorld.print()V

Tags: java, c

I am trying to call native methods from a JAVA class. This JAVA class after I compiled it  and created the [.h] version for it and details all the definition within the [.c] file then after.The next step followed creation of  [.dll] file that I loaded with the JAVA class within the static parameters.

Now when I try to run my program, it gives me the following error :

> **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: sample.HelloWorld.print()V**

I don't understand as to how to map the native methods from my JAVA program?

**More explanation with code :**

I have a [HelloWorld.java] class file that has the native method called [print()] method declaration :

```
package sample;
public class HelloWorld{
    public native void print();
    static{
        System.loadLibrary("HelloWorld");
    }
}
```

Now, on compilation, I get the [.class] file version of it. The next I created the [.h] and [.c] file having the definition for the native method [print()] as follows :

**HellWorld.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<jni.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include "HelloWorld.h"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_print
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject jobj){
          printf("Hello there!!!!!!");
          return;          
  }
```

Now when I build this [.c] file, it generates the required [.dll] file that is needed. Everything works just fine with no errors and the message gets printed of print() method when I invoke the JAVA file.

The main problem arises when I try to call this **print()** method in **HelloWorld.java** class file from different class, **Invoker.java** class file. Then this generates the exception :

> **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: sample.HelloWorld.print()V**

I do not get why this happens so when I do it? Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you following a tutorial?

Comment: Some code that shows *how* you're loading/implementing would be helpful.

Comment: I have edited the my question with some code implementation believing that this might help you in better understanding my problem.

Comment: did you specify the library path when you start your application? e.g. -Djava.library.path=xxxx/HelloWorld.dll

Comment: I am using ECLIPSE IDE for the development purpose. Where do I set this library path in ECLIPSE?

Comment: @CodingPassionate, you would define that in the run configuration of your application: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957700/how-to-set-the-java-library-path-from-eclipse

Comment: I see there is no one replying this thread. Please help me sorting out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

the JNICALL function name in the .c file should be exact as that in the HelloWorld.h file

see this [link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2279602) for more info