# Unable to load library 'libtesseract302': The specified module could not be found

Tags: java

All - I am trying to use tess4j in my Java project. I have followed the following steps -

1. copied the jar files from /dist and /lib as a external jar files while creating the project.
2. Copied the /tessdata and libtesseract302.dll to the project root and even in src folder of the project.
3. Below is the code(tess4j example code in sf) -

   ```
   import java.io.File;
   import net.sourceforge.tess4j.*;

   public class ReadingImage {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           File imageFile = new File("C:\\Documents and Settings\\T9SAUR\\My Documents\\Downloads\\Tess4J-1.1-src\\Tess4J\\eurotext.tif");
           Tesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance();
           try {
               String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
               System.out.println(result);
           } catch (TesseractException e) {
               System.err.println(e.getMessage());
           }
       }
   }
   ```

yet my code is giving the error. As per the other post on the same topic, I checked the JVM version (32 bit) and eclipse version(32 bit). Please let me know, where I went wrong.

Comment: @SSpoke - The error is Unable to load library 'libtesseract302': The specified module could not be found

Comment: I googled that error and found to specify exactly where the dll file is you could add `-Djava.library.path=path/to/your/dll` to your java run file and it should find the module. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/tesseract-ocr/LgHGzwqnGdk/jNzWS4sXtGEJ

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse to launch, then you need to specify the location of native libraries associated with the Tesseract jar.  See [How to set the java.library.path from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957700/how-to-set-the-java-library-path-from-eclipse/958074#958074)

Comment: I did exactly as mentioned in the link, but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JNA (or your framework/library uses JNA), in this case tess4j does uses

Try this

-Djna.library.path=${workspace_loc:/ocr-tess4j-example}/dll/win32-x86-64

or

-Djna.library.path=path/to/dlls