# how do I call sqljdbc_auth.dll

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, dll, jdbc

I'm using eclipse and want to make an sql database connection I put the sqljdbc_auth.dll in the buildpath

 I'm getting this error message

> Dec 18, 2013 10:45:54 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI clinit> 
>   WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path 
>   This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:7a06f...

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx#Connectingintegrated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem.

> -Djava.library.path=C:\bla\path\where\the\dll\is

just needed quotes around it like this

> "-Djava.library.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\jdbc\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x86"

Answer (score 4):

The DLL file has to be present in one of the locations of your `PATH` environment var.

It may already help to copy the file to the folder `windows\system32` or the `bin` folder of your JRE/JDK. Restart Eclipse and try again.

If this doesn't work you can also specify the parameter `java.library.path` in your Eclipse `Run Configuration` like this:

```
-Djava.library.path=C:\bla\path\where\the\dll\is
```

Alternativly you can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957700/how-to-set-the-java-library-path-from-eclipse) which describes in detail how to setup the parameter for a complete project.

**See also:**

- [Creating a Java application launch configuration](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-java-local-configuration.htm)

Comment: I tried that. I get this: Error: Could not find or load main class Files

Comment: And possibly unrelated to *this* question.

Answer (score 0):

If the JDBC is still using 32 bit sqljdbc_auth.dll, it could be because the PATH variable has found 64 bit dll before it gets to the newly added PATH environment variable. Add location of the 64 bit  sqljdbc_auth.dll in the very beginning of the PATH system variable. In my case it was

`C:\nilster\JDBC\sqlserver-sqljdbc_4.2\enu\auth\x64`

This helped me get around to the issue.