# Java not able to load library in Eclipse project

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, dll, java-native-interface

I'm trying to load a .dll into my java/c++ project in eclipse. I've created the .dll in order for my Java project to use it with the JNI, but when I try to load the library, I get this message: "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no hpaprogram in java.library.path". My main class is located in a different directory than the dll, but I used the flag `-Djava.library.path=jni` in VM Arguments. I have no idea what could be going wrong, and I've been debugging this for hours.

Here's my git repo: https://github.com/zalbhathena/Thesis-Test-Application

Also I'm using OS X if that matters.

EDIT: Here's a post I found. it states that I need a jnilib, not a dll. I've made the changes yet I still get the same error. I'm doing exactly what he is but in eclipse, so I'm not sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps:
[How to set the java.library.path from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957700/how-to-set-the-java-library-path-from-eclipse)

Also, maybe we can try this another way, if not already tried.

a) Create your java class having the native methods defined.

b) Use javah to generate the required header and c files (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javah.html).

c) Put in your code in the C file generated and use gcc to create a library of the same.