# using the jlwgl and slick libraries

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I got the following Error as I compiled my program using the **jlwgl** and the **slick library**:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in
>   java.library.path

There are really many posts on that ! But I really didn't get the solutions of any of them. I think, that for example the description on [this site](http://lwjgl.org/faq.php) probably explained everything . But I don't know what they mean by:

> Specify the path to it using -Djava.library.path=

It would be very kind if you could give me a step by step explanation for dummies.

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and my IDE is eclipse

Comment: What IDE are you using? This is a simple fix, I can help you with it.

Comment: I am working with eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957700/how-to-set-the-java-library-path-from-eclipse):

Go to the library settings for your projects and for each LWJGL library go to the tree view in the library tab. Each library has items for source, javadoc and native library locations.

Select project, right click->properties, "java build path", "libraries" tab, select a jar, expand it, select "Native library location", click "edit...", folder chooser dialog will appear)

Comment: Okay, I probably messed too much up in my project.. I started a new one and did all the stuff again and it worked :) thank you !