# Gurobi UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, eclipse, gurobi

I am trying to install Gurobi under Academic Licence on Ubuntu 14.04. I have read the following post about the `UnsatisfiedLinkError`: [stackoverflow.com/questions/...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761348/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-gurobijni56-in-jav). But that didnt help me. I have extracted the zip in my `opt` folder. I have placed the licence file in `/opt/gurobi600/linux64/lib/gurobi.lic`.

I am trying to run the `Callback.java` example in Eclipse.

I have as Java VM argument: `-Djava.library.path=/opt/gurobi600/linux64/lib/`. I have as program argument: `/opt/gurobi600/linux64/examples/data/qafiro.lp`. The environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set on `/opt/gurobi600/linux64/lib/gurobi.lic`

And I get the following stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/gurobi600/linux64/lib/libGurobiJni60.so: libgurobi60.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1880)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
    at gurobi.GurobiJni.<clinit>(GurobiJni.java:197)
    at gurobi.GRBEnv.<init>(GRBEnv.java:16)
    at gurobi.GRBEnv.<init>(GRBEnv.java:11)
    at main.Callback.main(Callback.java:135)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all working properly now. I have removed the VM arguments in the run configurations menu, so that's all empty in Eclipse. I have changed the environment variables in Eclipse, they are now set to:

```
GUROBI_HOME      = /opt/gurobi600/linux64/
GRB_LICENSE_FILE = /opt/gurobi600/linux64/gurobi.lic
LD_LIBRARY_PATH  = /opt/gurobi600/linux64/lib/
PATH             = /opt/gurobi600/linux64/bin/
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, I had tried for hours searching how to do this

Comment: Small typo! - It is GRB_LICEN**SE_FILE. Also if your application is a web app, then you can set the System property like below `System.setProperty( "ld.library.path", "/opt/gurobi600/linux64/lib/")`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I changed the LICENCE typo.