# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when running java command as sudo

Tags: java, linux

[image]

As you can see, it works when running as non sudo. I however need to run it as sudo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced this error this comes when there is classpath issue. Set classpath from command prompt, do via terminal, like java -Djava.library.path=blahblahblah...
 liked helping you.

Comment: Added the code, displays the following `java.library.path=/home/karl/workspace/sslarp/lib/:/usr...`, which is correct. Which directory shall I add to the `CLASSPATH`?

Comment: do one thing add this line System.out.println(props.getProperty("java.library.path")); it will display full classpath, search for class containing method getmacip in given classpath

Comment: check if java home is added in above.

Comment: Output is as following `/home/karl/workspace/sslarp/lib:/home/karl/workspace/sslarp/lib`

Comment: i think your java home is not in classpath, to set it from eclipse refer following link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957700/how-to-set-the-java-library-path-from-eclipse

Comment: Ah, that is via Eclipse, I am forced to go via the terminal in this case for the sudo. :/

Comment: Karl, you can also do via terminal, like  java -Djava.library.path=blahblahblah...

Comment: Doh! Sorry I misunderstood the link, and it did indeed work with sudo via the -Djava. Why is this, any explanation? P.S. update your answer and I'll happily accept! (Don't remove the code though, it was helpful)

Answer (score 0):

Try either using `sudo -E` (which will pass your environment variables to the `sudo` environment), or pass the specific environment variables that you wish:

```
sudo LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH" java ...
```

(You may not need to pass the `CLASSPATH`, you can try with or without it).