# Put javax.comm .dll library on another location?

Tags: java, windows, serial-port, javax.comm

i am using successfully javax.comm to communicate with Serial ports and Serial Adapters. This file is needed for proper function:

`win32com.dll`

According to the main page, it have to be located here:

```
(javaPath + "/bin/win32com.dll")
```

(`javaPath` is `java.home`)

Unfortunatelly, after a Java-Update, this file is deleted, so I run into Problems on every Java-Update.
My questions is: Is it possible to locate the `win32.com.dll` file in another Location without running into Problems? Maybe ist possible to manupulate the Java libary path?

Many thanks for everyone who could help.
However, please excuse my English.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

use java -Djava.library.path=

Check this link "matt b" answer
[How to set the java.library.path from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957700/how-to-set-the-java-library-path-from-eclipse)

There is a great article for various of setting lib path
check this link also 
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-library-path-what-is-it-and-how-to-use/