# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java in java.library.path

Tags: java, opencv

I have the code that is for to take snapshot but i am facing the problem of 'no opencv_java in java.library.java'. I have tried the all methods of opencv (install it, setup  the .dll file, seted up .so file) but as like as before the problem remain same.

```
import org.opencv.core.*;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture;

public class web
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture(0);
        if (!camera.isOpened())
        {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        else
        {
            Mat frame = new Mat();
            while (true)
            {
                if (camera.read(frame))
                {
                    System.out.println("Frame Obtained");
                    System.out.println("Captured Frame Width " +
                                       frame.width() + " Height " + frame.height());
                    Highgui.imwrite("camera.jpg", frame);
                    System.out.println("OK");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        camera.release();
    }
}
```

Now how can I overcome this problem, I have already did the NATIVE library path 
    `-Djava.library.path="C:\path to the .dll file"`

Comment: Which version of opencv are you using?

Comment: **opencv 249***

Comment: Try this answer, maybe it can work for you too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42996093/7478712

Answer (score 0):

I'm using fedora linux and i installed the opencv-java package using the package manager "dnf" then i got the same error so i just created some directories `/usr/java/packages/lib` then i copied the whole content of the `/lib/java/` into the dirs that created . and it SOLVED my probled

give it a try