# Setting an Eclipse project to use a patched runtime library

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, runtime, patch

I'm trying to create an Eclipse project that runs a locally patched version of `rt.jar`.  By local, I mean local to the Eclipse project.  The Eclipse project contains a folder called `runtimes`, which contains a copy of the default runtime jars.  I've set the project's classpath to use these library jars and not the system jars (using [IJavaProject.setRawClasspath](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/IJavaProject.html#setRawClasspath-org.eclipse.jdt.core.IClasspathEntry:A-org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor-)).

The Eclipse project has a single test class.

```
import java.io.File;

public class POC {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("File Resource:");
        ClassLoader loader = POC.class.getClassLoader();
        System.out.println(loader.getResource("java/io/File.class"));

        System.out.println("\nLibrary Path:");
        String librarypath = System.getProperty("java.library.path");
        String[] librarypathEntries = librarypath.split(File.pathSeparator);
        for(String lp : librarypathEntries){
            System.out.println(lp);
        }

        System.out.println("\nClasspath:");
        String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
        String[] classpathEntries = classpath.split(File.pathSeparator);
        for(String cp : classpathEntries){
            System.out.println(cp);
        }

    }

}
```

Currently it prints something to the effect of...

```
File Resource:
jar:file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar!/java/io/File.class

Library Path:
/Users/ben/Library/Java/Extensions
/Library/Java/Extensions
/Network/Library/Java/Extensions
/System/Library/Java/Extensions
/usr/lib/java
.

Classpath:
/Users/ben/.../workspace/Test/runtimes/resources.jar
/Users/ben/.../workspace/Test/runtimes/rt.jar
/Users/ben/.../workspace/Test/runtimes/jsse.jar
/Users/ben/.../workspace/Test/runtimes/jce.jar
/Users/ben/.../workspace/Test/runtimes/charsets.jar
/Users/ben/.../workspace/Test/runtimes/jfr.jar
/Users/ben/.../workspace/Test/runtimes/JObjC.jar
/Users/ben/.../workspace/Test/runtimes/dnsns.jar
/Users/ben/.../workspace/Test/runtimes/localedata.jar
/Users/ben/.../workspace/Test/runtimes/sunec.jar
/Users/ben/.../workspace/Test/runtimes/sunjce_provider.jar
/Users/ben/.../workspace/Test/runtimes/sunpkcs11.jar
/Users/ben/.../workspace/Test/runtimes/zipfs.jar
/Users/ben/.../workspace/Test/runtimes/MRJToolkit.jar
/Users/ben/.../workspace/Test/bin
```

Since apparently setting the classpath isn't enough, I tried editing the `Run Configurations` and setting a few variations of the VM argument for [-Xbootclasspath](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15062/optionx.htm#i1018570) as suggested by [this article](http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2010/02/replacing-and-patching-java-application-and-core-classes/).

Example: `-Xbootclasspath/p:/Users/.../workspace/Test/runtimes/rt.jar;` This seemed to have no effect on the File Resource output (it always loads the original implementation of File).

I also tried `-Djava.library.path=/Users/ben/.../Test/runtimes/`, but that didn't change the File Resource either.

I'm wondering if it's related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957700/how-to-set-the-java-library-path-from-eclipse).

P.S. I know applications that override a class in the rt.jar file are a violation of the Java SE run-time environment binary code license. This is not for production use, I just want to see it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok turns out `-Xbootclasspath` was all I needed.  My runtime jar modifications resulted in an invalid `rt.jar` file, which was the root cause of my frustrations.

Answering my own question in case someone else finds it useful.

[image]