# Eclipse is unable to access the system environment variable

Tags: eclipse, jms, ibm-mq, mq

I am trying to connect with a remote MQ using a simple JMS program using IBM MQ.The MQ has a security exits which needs to be configured in JMS code.

factory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
 factory.setSecurityExit(secExit);

The security exits has native library files(.dll) that needs to be there in the system PATH(C:\securityexits) variable.When I tried running my JMS code it works fine outside eclipse environment using system JDK but it is not working in eclipse. I am getting the following exception.

Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no Acmqsecx in java.library.path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the java.library.path from Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957700/how-to-set-the-java-library-path-from-eclipse)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957700/how-to-set-the-java-library-path-from-eclipse

Comment: I tried all the solutions mentioned in the post before asking this question.I added Native library folder in the Build path.I tried adding the -Djava.library.path in the VM arguments tab. The code works perfectly outside eclipse(in command prompt and Gradle) but it is failing to execute in eclipse.I use Eclipse Mars.1 Release (4.5.1).Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Deepak, I am facing this issue. Can you please advise what is the value to be assigned to -Djava.library.path. I mean which path needs to be assigned