# Cannot connect spring-data with SQL server ( Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll )

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, intellij-idea

I'm using windows 10 , when I try to compile my project I get the following error  :

> c.m.s.jdbc.internals.AuthenticationJNI   : Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll
>
> 2016-05-11 02:18:00.558 ERROR 5424 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.
>
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication.
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:170) ~[sqljdbc4-2.0.jar:na]
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2338) ~[sqljdbc4-2.0.jar:na]
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:1929) ~[sqljdbc4-2.0.jar:na]
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41) ~[sqljdbc4-2.0.jar:na]

What I tried so  far :
1. copy the authsql dll in jre of intellij idea => nothing
2. copy the dll to system32 => JVM error ACCESS_VIOLATION

```
Sring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=MyTest;integratedSecurity=true;
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

The connection works in Datagrip I can connect to the database without any problem but intellij I get this error is there a way to fix it?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2015/01/09/jdbc-this-driver-is-not-configured-for-integrated-authentication/

Comment: @Suganthan I tried all solutions even those in comments doesn't work.

Comment: have a look at this answer.
This might help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957700/how-to-set-the-java-library-path-from-eclipse/958074#958074

Comment: @TahirHussainMir I really don't know how to do the same thing in intellij idea

Answer (score 0):

```
Sring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=MyTest;integratedSecurity=true
```

try changing ports to 3306 and see what happens:

```
Sring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:3306;databaseName=MyTest;integratedSecurity=true
```

Comment: I get the following error :Prelogin error: host localhost port 3306 Unexpected response type:74

Comment: this may sound redundant or silly, but have a look at the firewall if that is open on port 3306 if that check okay look to see if SQL services in admin settings in control panel are running. comtrol panel.> administration tools > services> mysql or SQL57

Comment: the port 3306 is taken by mysql I'm trying to use SQL server