# How to remove this Exception "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniopencv_objdetect in java.library.path"

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, javacv, face-recognition

I'm working on Face Recognition Project by using OpenCV 2.4.9, JavaCV 0.7,JAVA version 8 and Eclipse IDE... I am getting these Exceptions continuously.. Is there something wrong in the follwoing code? It's not my complette code...
Please Someone help me as soon as possible...

```
import com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect;
Loader.load(opencv_objdetect.class);
```

Exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniopencv_objdetect in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:711)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:586)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:540)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect.<clinit>(opencv_objdetect.java:91)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:561)
    at FaceRecognizer.<init>(FaceRecognizer.java:56)
    at FaceRecognizer.main(FaceRecognizer.java:112)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\XYX\AppData\Local\Temp\javacpp183187286948746\jniopencv_objdetect.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:700)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: It's not your code, you've got a dll problem. Either jniopencv_objdetect.dll is not in the java.library.path or a dll it depends on is missing.

Comment: So how can i add it? you know any possible solution??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html) gives a description of how to get an OpenCV Java sample running. There should be two things that you need to do:

1. You need to call System.LoadLibrary specifying the OpenCV DLLs that it uses

   System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
2. Make sure the DLL in somewhere where it can be found by the JVM. There are a few ways if doing that. I don't use Eclipse but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957700/how-to-set-the-java-library-path-from-eclipse) seems to give a good explanation. Alternatively, a simple bodge just to get things working is to drop the DLL into the windows\system32 directory

Finally there may be an issue if you are running a 64 bit JVM but trying to use a 32 bit DLL. If you are still having trouble make sure you are using matching JVM and DLL.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of the java libraries that you are using in your project is using jni calls that uses dll files. Do you have the library installed correctly? It looks like it is called opencv or something that is related to jniopencv_objdetect.dll