# Serial port library giving error java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:

Tags: java, eclipse, serial-port

I have downloaded this library from this link http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page. I have google a number of pages and first I add via the build path method and add the RXTXcomm.jar. Then I have also add here C:\Program Files(86)\Java\jre7\lib\ext folder also added this .jar file. Yet I still getting this error when I try to run or compile my programme on eclipse

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:123)
    at read1.TwoWaySerialComm.connect(TwoWaySerialComm.java:21)
    at read1.TwoWaySerialComm.main(TwoWaySerialComm.java:108)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `java.library.path` when you are starting your program.  This will let Java be able to find the native C code that is used in order to talk with the serial ports.

Comment: I dont get you what path to set is it in eclipse?

Comment: In Eclipse, when you run a program, there is a dialog that you can use to set the program arguments and the VM arguments.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957700/how-to-set-the-java-library-path-from-eclipse) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

This library as been deprecated. Use new libraries like serialpundit, pyserial etc.