# Export Native library to external Package in Eclipse not working. is it a Bug?

Tags: java, eclipse, package, java-native-library

I was about to report a but to Eclipse, but I was thinking to give this a chance here first:

If I add an external package, the application cannot find the referenced native library, except in the case specified at the below:

If my workspace consists of a single project, and I import an external package 'EX_package.jar' from a folder outside of the project folder, I can assign a folder to the native library location via:

mouse over package -> 
right click -> 
properties -> 
Native Library -> 
Enter your folder.

This does not work. In runtime the application does not load the library, System.mapLibraryName(Path) also does not work.

Further more, if I create a User Library, and add the package to it and define a folder for the native library it still does not.

If it works for you then I have a major bug since it does not work on my computer I test this in any combination I could think of, including adding the path to the windows PATH parameter, and so many other ways I can't even start to remember, nothing worked, I played with this for hours and had a colleague try to assist me, but we both came up empty.

Further more, if I have a main project that is dependent on few other projects in my workspace, and they all need to use the same 'EX_package.jar' I **MUST** supply a **HARD COPY INTO EACH OF THEM**, it will **ONLY** (I can't stress the ONLYNESS, I got freaked out by this) work if I have a hard copy of the package in ALL of the project folders that the main project has a dependency on, and ONLY if I configure the Native path in each of them!!

[**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661320/how-to-add-native-library-to-java-library-path-with-eclipse-launch-instead-of) also didn't do the trick.

please tell me there is a solution to this, this drives me nuts...

**Update:**

if anyone wants to try this for them selfs you can try to use JMF.jar and to refer to the native dlls, or the jmf.properties file, on my XP, I refer to the dll files and I don't need the jmf.properties file.

Thanks,
Adam Zehavi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed the point that Eclipse does not export the native library.

here is a solution to what I was facing: [Other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046621/how-to-capture-video-using-jmf-but-without-installing-jmf)