# Java Eclipse Importing 32 bit DLL on a 64 bit machine

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to use the `thinkgear.dll` library to connect with a NeuroSky Mindset.

The developer tools include a ThinkGear.java class, which is a wrapper around the thinkgear.dll. The dll is only 32 bit compatible. I get a Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform error when trying to run the program. This is only going to be run on my computer, not distributed. I've read that I have to run the jre in 32 bit mode or something?

Also, I am not sure I have set up the library to reference it properly. How should I do that, starting with a brand new project, where should I put the dll and thinkgear.java to be able to use the methods in my NeuroSkyApp class? Sorry, I am very new to java, I don't really understand all of this yet.

Here is a screenshot of what I have in Eclipse:

[image: Eclipse Screenshot]

Comment: sounds pretty reasonable to run it in 32-bit mode, then :P

Comment: add the folder "native" to the build-path for a better reference, by: Right-click (on folder) -> Build Path -> Add to Build Path...

Answer (score 2):

You need to install a 32-bit JRE and configure the build environment for your project in Eclipse accordingly.

To add an external dll to your project, you might find useful information here: [How to add native library to "java.library.path" with Eclipse launch (instead of overriding it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661320/how-to-add-native-library-to-java-library-path-with-eclipse-launch-instead-of)

Comment: I have a 32 bit jre installed, its at C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7

Comment: Try http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-choose_config_jre.htm However, using google to figure that out is not too complicated ;)

Comment: Okay, I have make it run in a 32 bit jre. But now I am getting:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: project.ThinkGear.GetDriverVersion()I
 at project.ThinkGear.GetDriverVersion(Native Method)
 at project.NeuroSkyApp.createWindow(NeuroSkyApp.java:20)
 at project.NeuroSkyApp.main(NeuroSkyApp.java:8)

Comment: This is the NeuroSkyApp class, the get driver version is just a test to see if the dll loading worked.  http://pastebin.com/Nf2rD0rx

Comment: That shows you that your dll is not found. Either specify the java.library.path variables accordingly (see above) or try to set the path in eclipse: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-choose_config_jre.htm

Comment: I'm still not getting this. I configured it to run it in the 32 bit jre. I guess I am not referencing the dll correctly. How do I set the path in eclipse? Should I make a jar out of the ThinkGear.java file and make it have native dependencies, I kind of know how to do that.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how to help you further. The links I provided describe how to set up your library path in eclipse. Alternatively, you can try to run the program from your command line. Then, you have to start java with -Djava.library.path=your_path

Comment: Okay, I have put the .dll in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin because that was in the path it printed out. It is still getting the same error, is there a specific thing I have to do?

Comment: Perhaps you could try to let the PATH variable point to the location where the DLL is. Otherwise, I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: But doesn't my unsatisfiedlinkerror mean that java is having trouble loading the dll, as in it has it loaded, but can't find methods?

Comment: Perhaps your dll internally references methods in an external dll that cannot be found.