# How to include shared object files in maven project

Tags: java, maven, swig, shared-objects, gdal

I am using an external c++ library (gdal/ogr) which creates shared object files so that java can utilize its functionality. The problem is that I am not really sure what I am supposed to do with these .so files and how I am supposed to get maven to use them when building the project.
I found [this](https://code.google.com/p/mavennatives/) tutorial on how to include shared object files

but when I follow the directions given, I just get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:73)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:95)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:112)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:135)
    at com.googlecode.nativedependencies.example.App.main(App.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

For context on the relevant .so files and how they are generated, see the following [link](https://github.com/VertNet/reproject/wiki/GDAL-Java-Bindings) on compiling gdal/ogr with java bindings.

I am just looking for the most robust way to include these files so that I can, to the greatest extent possible, use the gdal/ogr library in java the way I would any other normal java library.

Answer (score 0):

I think this plugin help you build java project. But you still needs to inform JVM where are the native files.

See [How to add native library to “java.library.path” with Eclipse launch (instead of overriding it)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2309723/651140) or simple one [How to Load a Java Native/Shared Library (.so)](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-loadLibrary-Linux.asp)

You need to override (in the same console before you open eclipse or run your java program)

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH = "${workspace_loc}/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
```

or add to java command:

```
-Djava.library.path="${workspace_loc:project}\lib;${env_var:PATH}"
```