# How to build java desktop application with arcobject ( Arcgis 10 )?

Tags: java, swing, awt, arcgis, arcobjects

i try to build java standalone appplication with Arcgis

i already instal Arcgis Desktop 10 and ArcObject SDK for java platform

i just try to getting started ..

so i use this [tutorial](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.1/ArcGISDevHelp/DevelopmentEnvs/Java/GettingStarted_Eng.htm)

then i include libraries arcobjects.jar from my arcgis installation

C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\java\lib\arcobjects.jar

into my netbeans project

then i write this (similiar with tutorial)

```
package gis;

import com.esri.arcgis.beans.globe.GlobeBean;
import com.esri.arcgis.system.AoInitialize;
import com.esri.arcgis.system.EngineInitializer;
import com.esri.arcgis.system.esriLicenseProductCode;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


    public class Gis {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
             EngineInitializer.initializeVisualBeans();
             new AoInitialize().initialize(esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeEngine);
             JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Hello, Sphere!");
             jFrame.setSize(300, 300);
             jFrame.getContentPane().add(new GlobeBean(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
             jFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                 public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                     try {
                         new AoInitialize().shutdown();
                         System.exit(0);
                     }
                     catch (IOException ex) {
                         System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                         System.exit(1);
                     }
                 }
             });
             jFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

its error..
the output is

```
Could not load native libraries.
```

my question :

1. how to make it right?
2. how to build java standalone application with arcgis? (and what kind of arcgis technologies i need? )

   - i already goggling for 2 days but i still can't figure it out
   - i already go to their forum.. but its difficult to find the tread post page. so i end up here.

Comment: Have you included the native libraries (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/661320/1076463)) ?

Comment: no.. i don't know what to do..
from my arcgis instalation, its also instal another jre (its in arcgis directory)
so i confuse how to set the path.. (into my default jre(from oracle) or to arcgis jre)..
i already try it but its still error..
i think maybe i miss another configuration..

Comment: i dont know the location of the native libraries

Answer (score 1):

Are you using 64 bit JRE/JDK? If so, use 32 bit JRE/JDK when building Java AO apps for ArcGIS Engine or Desktop. 64 bit JRE/JDK can be used for building extensions for ArcGIS Server.

Thanks!
Ajit