# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path in runnable jar

Tags: java, arduino, unsatisfiedlinkerror, rxtx

I am having a problem when I try to use my Arduino in my java application when I export it to a runnable jar file. When I run the application on the IDE it runs just fine, the exported jar on the same machine too, but when I run it on a different machine I get a the

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path.
```

I am sure that I have added the RXTXcomm.jar and the rxtxserial.dll to the build path as shown in the picture below [build path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WtDn.png)

In the other machines where I put my jars, I copy mentioned two files in the exact same location but the error persists.

Comment: Have you set the `java.library.path` ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661320/how-to-add-native-library-to-java-library-path-with-eclipse-launch-instead-of

Comment: Your jar file needs the RXTXcomm.jar in its classpath at runtime as well... unless you're using something to build an uber jar for it.  I believe common Java build systems like Maven and Gradle have plugins to build uber-jars.

Comment: Yes, I added the the RXTXcomm.jar and the rxtxserial.dll in the build path, there are a link of an image showing this in my question.

Comment: @Powerlord thank you I am going to try to build with Maven but I thought the simplest way to achieve this is to always copy past the needed files in the same location of your build path, in my app I have another library (jmf) and it runs on every machine with this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to copy the contents of the RXTXcomm.jar into the exported JAR-File.

Place the dlls into jre_home/bin/ or in your programs main folder.

Comment: The dll file is not inside the jar I just add them in the build path in the native library location

Comment: This should be correct. Either place the dll in your applications main directory, or place it in jre_home/bin/

Comment: when I place them in the jre_home/bin/ do I need to specify the build path to go look for them there or it is done automatically without specifying it?

Comment: placing them in jre_home solved it as you said, thank you.