# How to deploy Spring Boot application and OpenCV library to heroku?

Tags: java, spring-boot, opencv, heroku

I'm setting up a spring boot application with opencv 4.10. 
My application can run well on localhost with VM arguments 
`-Djava.library.path=/home/nopain2110/development/opencv/opencv/build/lib`

But how can I deploy this app to heroku include opencv native library? 
Thanks!

Comment: you are referencing a library that must be present in the heroku system; since you are using spring boot and maven import the library in the pom, this question might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37901505/java-opencv-from-maven