# Error loading OpenCV library from Maven repository

Tags: java, maven, opencv

I want to execute a simple OpenCV code to test that the library is well loaded by Maven.

This is the code:

```
package helloworld;
import org.opencv.core.*;

public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        nu.pattern.OpenCV.loadLibrary();
        System.out.println("Hey World !");
        Mat mat = Mat.eye(3, 3, CvType.CV_8UC1);
    }
}
```

And this is the console output I get, with the two errors, when I try to run it:

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: sys_paths
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2417)
> at nu.pattern.OpenCV.loadLibrary(OpenCV.java:207)
> at helloworld.Hello.main(Hello.java:9)
>
> Hey World !
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_eye(III)J
> at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_eye(Native Method)
> at org.opencv.core.Mat.eye(Mat.java:1467)
> at helloworld.Hello.main(Hello.java:11)

I got the maven repository linking looking at that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37901505/java-opencv-from-maven#42569334).

Would you have any idea about what is causing that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try downloading a library from another repository.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.2-1</version>
</dependency>
```

You can see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56710956/java-8-opencv-easy-example-unsatisfiedlinkerror#56857762) to the post with a similar problem.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I "resolved" my problem changing the dependency as you did, and with nu.pattern.OpenCV.loadLocally(); but every tiime I launch the program the error "You have loaded library /tmp/opencv_openpnp.../libopencv_java342.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'."

Comment: Run this command: 
execstack -c /tmp/opencv_openpnp.../libopencv_java342.so. This should help