# Java 8 opencv easy example UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, opencv, java-8

I would like to learn opencv so I wanted to run this code code example.

I have downloaded package from opencv 3.4.2, rigidly added in intellij, java version 8. Version 3.20 mi works properly but needs a higher version of 3.4.2 or higher. Please help, I can not do what. This is my code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        System.out.println("Welcome to OpenCV " + Core.VERSION);
        Mat m = new Mat(5, 10, CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(0));
        System.out.println("OpenCV Mat: " + m);
        Mat mr1 = m.row(1);
        mr1.setTo(new Scalar(1));
        Mat mc5 = m.col(5);
        mc5.setTo(new Scalar(5));
        System.out.println("OpenCV Mat data:\n" + m.dump());
    }
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Work\opencv\opencv\build\java\x64\opencv_java342.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2430)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2487)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2684)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2649)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:829)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1867)
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to load .dll or .so library using:

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
```

Or

```
System.load(PATH_TO_NATIVE_LIB);
```

Next you need to add dependency to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.2-1</version>
</dependency>
```

Library and dependency versions must be the same.