# Processing 3.3.7 - Using processing.io in Eclipse, but no io.jar

Tags: eclipse, processing

I'm trying to use Processing's IO library in Eclipse, but instead of a `.jar` to add as a dependency there's only this `libprocessing-io.so` file. How can I add this to Eclipse?

Comment: What operating system are you planning on using the I/O library for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/io/index.html):

> This library is only available for embedded Linux boards with the necessary kernel drivers, such as the Raspberry Pi.

Which means you can't use the library on every single system.

Assuming you're on the correct system, you can view / download the source code of the library from GitHub [here](https://github.com/processing/processing/tree/master/java/libraries/io).

This library was designed to be used in the Processing editor, so I don't see a nicely packaged `.jar` file anyway. You're probably going to have to compile and bundle the source up yourself, or maybe you could use the Processing editor to download the library, then import the library into Eclipse.

The `.so` file is a native file that you need to add to Eclipse. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661320/how-to-add-native-library-to-java-library-path-with-eclipse-launch-instead-of), especially the second answer.

Comment: This is what I did. There's a build.xml that actually generates the needed jar. But of course I still have to keep the .so in the same folder.

Comment: @user1854611 I don't know the specifics of how the library loads the native dependencies, but in general you'll have to add native dependencies to Eclipse using the approach in that last link in my answer.